# How to add single quotes on a join?

Tags: ruby

I have the following data structure:

```
cmd = [ '-A', 'apples', -b 'bored' ]
```

I need to pass it to an `su` command as

```
su some_user -c '-A apples -b bored'
```

Is there a way to do this on a `join`?

Right now I am thinking this is a two step process but there has to be a better way:

```
options = [ '-A', 'apples', '-b' 'bored' ].join(' ')
quoted_options = "\'#{options}\'\"
```

I have about four more options, but figured I would save some time by truncating the samples.

Comment: `['-A', 'apples', '-b' 'bored']` missing comma after `-b` it is typo?

Comment: @Зелёный Most likely but `'a' 'b'` is still syntactically correct.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, but OP `options` variable contain `"-A apples -bbored"` if comma missing. Nevermind now....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could interpolate:

`options = "\'#{[ '-A', 'apples', '-b', 'bored' ].join(' ')}\'"`

That will give you the quotes in one line.

Comment: Cool. I agree with you above, I think this is the only way. I was performing the same action, but in two steps.

Comment: This is technically correct, but actually wrong for shell usage.

Answer (score 4):

If you're composing a shell command you need to be careful:

```
options = [ '-A', 'apples', '-b', 'bored' ]

require "shellescape"

argument = "'" + Shellwords.shellescape(options.join(' ')) + "'"
```

Be extremely careful when composing shell arguments. It's easy to trip up and execute arbitrary commands by accident.

Even better would be to use the `system` call with distinct arguments to avoid shell interpolation:

```
system("su", "user", "-c", options.join(' '))
```

Then there's no need to escape them at all.

Comment: Another case of `system` FTW!

Comment: I think the shellescape looks like a good solution, but due to the nature of the application, I need to keep to core/std libs.  For the second option, I actually did use the system code initially, however, however the su did not like the fact the command was not quoted. I imagine this would have happened with open3 as well.